# Ajax page load not running content JS

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a PHP document with jQuery that listens for clicks on certain links and uses ajax to load the contents of a page dynamically. One of those pages had some  tags in it for embedding a dynamic shopping cart. If I load this content directly, it works. However when the content is loaded via ajax, nothing happens and it doesn't fire off.

The Ajax Code

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $("a").click(function(e){
            pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
            if(pageurl!=window.location) {
                window.history.pushState({path: pageurl}, '', pageurl);
            }

            var post_id = $(this).attr("rel")
            var post_content = $("#main-content").load("http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>/ajax/",{id:post_id}); // line 12

            $("#main-content").load("http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>/ajax/",{id:post_id}); // line 12

            return false;
        });
```

The Page Embed Code

```
<div id="my-store-1001"></div>
<div> 
    <script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?1001" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> xProductBrowser("categoriesPerRow=3","views=grid(10,3) list(60) table(60)","categoryView=grid","searchView=grid","id=my-store-1001","minicart_layout=MiniAttachToProductBrowser","default_category_id=0");</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamically loaded code doesn't actually have any event handlers attached to it. You need to use delegated event handling.

Try something like:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'a', (function(e){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $("a").click(function(e){
```

after that add this line which prevents loading,

```
e.preventdefault();
```